# Refresh listview with jQuery mobile version 1.0rc3

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a tablet application with the *jquery.mobile-1.0rc3* version. Previoulsy, I used the *jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1* version on another application, and it was possible to refresh a listview by doing **myListview.listview( "refresh" )**.

I'm having some problems doing the same with the new jquery.mobile-1.0rc3 version. Is it possible to do that with the new jquery.mobile-1.0rc3 version?

Thank you very much.

Here's a bit of the code:

```
var lists = $( '#posicaoIntegradaActivosList, #posicaoIntegradaPassivosList, #posicaoIntegradaOutrosList' );

lists.empty();

/* Fill the lists with jquery template */

lists.listview( "refresh" );
```

Error:

> uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: Your example code works as I've tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qSmJq/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/qSmJq/3/ and get the expected results without error. What version of jQuery are you running? RC3 requires 1.6.4

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code? And what if you do lists.listview(); before lists.listview( "refresh" );

Comment: Phill, the logic of your examples are the same as my code and it works as expected. I don't really understand what is wrong here and I'm using jQuery 1.6.4.

Comment: I've also tried lists.listview(); but it gives me another error! This isn't necessary because the listview is already initialized in the HTML.

Comment: Could you provide a working demo on http://jsfiddle.net with your code? Or give us a URL to test? This would help in debugging. Coming from A4.1 to RC3 a lot has changed, been re-factored, renamed, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Depending on when your code runs it may be running before the jQuery Mobile initialization process. jsFiddle by default runs code after the `load` event fires so the DOM is all setup and jQuery Mobile has done its initialization. If you change @Phill Pafford's jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/qSmJq/3/) to run on "no wrap (body)" rather than "onLoad" then you get the same error you are reporting. So I recommend either removing the `lists.listview('refresh');` line or putting your code inside either a `document.ready` or a `pageshow/pagecreate` event handler:

```
var lists = $( '#posicaoIntegradaActivosList, #posicaoIntegradaPassivosList, #posicaoIntegradaOutrosList' );

lists.empty();

/* Fill the lists with jquery template */

//lists.listview( "refresh" );
```

Here's a jsfiddle for running the code as soon as it is parsed by the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/qSmJq/5/

Or:

```
$(function () {
    var lists = $( '#posicaoIntegradaActivosList, #posicaoIntegradaPassivosList, #posicaoIntegradaOutrosList' );

    lists.empty();

    /* Fill the lists with jquery template */

    lists.listview( "refresh" );
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for wrapping your code in a `document.ready` event handler: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/qSmJq/4/

Or:

```
$('#my-page-id').on('pagecreate', function () {
    var lists = $( '#posicaoIntegradaActivosList, #posicaoIntegradaPassivosList, #posicaoIntegradaOutrosList' );

    lists.empty();

    /* Fill the lists with jquery template */

    //lists.listview( "refresh" );
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle for using the `pageshow` event: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/qSmJq/6/

And here is a jsfiddle for using the `pagecreate` event: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/qSmJq/7/

On a side note: if you want to detect whether or not jQuery Mobile has initialized a certain element you can check for the jQuery Mobile specific classes on the element:

```
$(function () {

    //cache lists
    var lists = $( '#posicaoIntegradaActivosList, #posicaoIntegradaPassivosList, #posicaoIntegradaOutrosList' );

    //iterate through the lists
    lists.each(function (index, value) {

        //cache this specific list
        var $value = $(value);

        /*add rows to this listview here*/

        //check if the listview has been initialized by jQuery Mobile by checking for the existence of the `ui-listview` class
        if ($value.hasClass('ui-listview')) {

            //since the class was found, refresh the already initialized element
            $value.listview('refresh');
        } else {

            //the class was not found, so initialize the widget
            $value.trigger('create');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Jasper, I followed your logic and it worked. The problem was that, at the time that I was tryign to refresh to listview, the widget wasn't even created so the code ended up like:

$( lists ).each( function() {
    ( $( this ).hasClass( 'ui-listview' ) ) ? $( this ).listview( 'refresh' ) : $( this ).trigger( 'create' );
});

Thank you very much!